# Нужна ли запятая в сложном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

«*О том, какая у меня классная новая работа будет приятно читать.*»

Вроде бы это обособление, или нет?

Answer (score 2):

*О том, какая у меня классная новая работа, будет приятно читать.*

Это не обособление (обособляются члены предложения в простом), а отделение простых предложений в сложноподчинённом с придаточным местоимённо-определительным.

И ещё: точка обычно ставится за кавычками.